# Error in node js : : ReferenceError: ProjectModel is not defined

Tags: node.js, api, post

I send a POST call from postman that contains a body, and in node js it does not find the body.
what my problem???
i'm need help,
thank you!!

this the server.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json())
const router = require('./routes/api')
app.use('/', router)

const conectionParams = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECT).then((res) => {
    console.log("db conneted!!")
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("error:: ", error)
});
app.listen(3001, () => { console.log("listening"); })
```

this the controller page:

```
router.post('/editProject' , async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        const project = req.body
        const newvalues = { "numberOfScans": project.numberOfScans }
        console.log("newvalues", req);
        await ProjectModel.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": project._id }, newvalues)
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'project updated', myproject: project })
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(400).json({ message: 'error:', error })
    }
})
module.exports = router
```

Comment: Where do you declare `ProjectModel`?

Comment: Do you import ProjectModel in your controller file? It would be helpful if you could post imports from that file.

Comment: Why do you say it can't find the body? On which line does the error occur?

Comment: The error in controller page in line 3' thank